# How do I do an Upsert Into Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view that has a list of jobs in it, with data like who they're assigned to and the stage they are in. I need to write a stored procedure that returns how many jobs each person has at each stage.

So far I have this (simplified):

```
DECLARE @ResultTable table 
(
  StaffName nvarchar(100),
  Stage1Count int,
  Stage2Count int
)

INSERT INTO @ResultTable (StaffName, Stage1Count)
  SELECT StaffName, COUNT(*) FROM ViewJob
  WHERE InStage1 = 1
  GROUP BY StaffName

INSERT INTO @ResultTable (StaffName, Stage2Count)
  SELECT StaffName, COUNT(*) FROM ViewJob
  WHERE InStage2 = 1
  GROUP BY StaffName
```

The problem with that is that the rows don't combine. So if a staff member has jobs in stage1 and stage2 there's two rows in @ResultTable. What I would really like to do is to update the row if one exists for the staff member and insert a new row if one doesn't exist.

Does anyone know how to do this, or can suggest a different approach?
I would really like to avoid using cursors to iterate on the list of users (but that's my fall back option).

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

**Edit: @Lee:** Unfortunately the InStage1 = 1 was a simplification. It's really more like WHERE DateStarted IS NOT NULL and DateFinished IS NULL.

**Edit: @BCS:** I like the idea of doing an insert of all the staff first so I just have to do an update every time. But I'm struggling to get those UPDATE statements correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC there is some sort of "On Duplicate" (name might be wrong) syntax that lets you update if a row exists (MySQL)

Alternately some form of:

```
INSERT INTO @ResultTable (StaffName, Stage1Count, Stage2Count)
  SELECT StaffName,0,0 FROM ViewJob
  GROUP BY StaffName

UPDATE @ResultTable Stage1Count= (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ViewJob
  WHERE InStage1 = 1
  @ResultTable.StaffName = StaffName)

UPDATE @ResultTable Stage2Count= (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ViewJob
  WHERE InStage2 = 1
  @ResultTable.StaffName = StaffName)
```

Comment: the "on duplicate" you mention is INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and the documentation is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think you're making it much harder than it is.  Won't this code work for what you're trying to do?

```
SELECT StaffName, SUM(InStage1) AS 'JobsAtStage1', SUM(InStage2) AS 'JobsAtStage2'
  FROM ViewJob
GROUP BY StaffName
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just check for existence and use the appropriate command. I believe this really does use a cursor behind the scenes, but it's the best you'll likely get:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE StaffName = @StaffName))
begin
    UPDATE MyTable SET ... WHERE StaffName = @StaffName
end
else
begin
    INSERT MyTable ...
end
```

SQL2008 has a new MERGE capability which is cool, but it's not in 2005.

Answer (score 1):

To get a real "upsert" type of query you need to use an if exists... type of thing, and this unfortunately means using a cursor.

However, you could run two queries, one to do your updates where there is an existing row, then afterwards insert the new one.  I'd think this set-based approach would be preferable unless you're dealing exclusively with small numbers of rows.

Answer (score 0):

The following query on your result table should combine the rows again. This is assuming that InStage1 and InStage2 are never both '1'.

```
select distinct(rt1.StaffName), rt2.Stage1Count, rt3.Stage2Count
from @ResultTable rt1
left join @ResultTable rt2 on rt1.StaffName=rt2.StaffName and rt2.Stage1Count is not null
left join @ResultTable rt3 on rt1.StaffName=rt2.StaffName and rt3.Stage2Count is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with a variation of BCS's answer. It wouldn't let me use a table variable though, so I had to make a temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #ResultTable
(
  StaffName nvarchar(100),
  Stage1Count int,
  Stage2Count int
)

INSERT INTO #ResultTable (StaffName)
  SELECT StaffName FROM ViewJob
  GROUP BY StaffName

UPDATE #ResultTable SET 
  Stage1Count= (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ViewJob V
    WHERE InStage1 = 1 AND 
        V.StaffName = @ResultTable.StaffName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    GROUP BY V.StaffName),
  Stage2Count= (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ViewJob V
    WHERE InStage2 = 1 AND 
        V.StaffName = @ResultTable.StaffName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    GROUP BY V.StaffName)

SELECT StaffName, Stage1Count, Stage2Count FROM #ResultTable

DROP TABLE #ResultTable
```